# CSS webkit overflow hidden and HTML element height

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

http://dev.anuary.com/1f1715ac-ad96-536a-a462-74381c7a2baf/test.html 
http://dev.anuary.com/1f1715ac-ad96-536a-a462-74381c7a2baf/test2.html

`test2.html` is the expected behaviour. However, it does not implement `test.html` CSS `body {overflow: hidden;}`. The latter is needed to prevent WekKit from *overscrolling*.

Essentially, I need a page with WebKit *overscrolling* disabled, with an element in DOM width and height 100% (100% meaning window size) and `overflow-y: scroll`. The only workaround that I managed to figure out is to use JavaScript to give fixed height to the  or the wrapping element. Though, preferably I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `height: 100%;` on `html` and `body` otherwise they will be much larger than the visible window size.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/8ejtP/

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```